# Python Runtime Recursion error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a basic Spark code in Spark 2.0.1.

```
sdf_content_cat=sqlContext.createDataFrame(content_catalogue)
sdf_content_cat.cache().take(2)
```

Here content_catalogue is a pandas data frame> Top 5 rows:

```
    com.learnfit.tax.core.externalID    com.learnfit.tax.core.label com.learnfit.tax.core.textContent
0   28245   DLR_MA-MFG Planning–Demand Processing Procedure DLR Maintenance Demand Processing Procedure for Manufacturing Planning
1   16583   TWDC_Harvard:Implementing Strategy  In many companies, senior business units and management are involved in the strategic planning process. Why? This ensures that a company’s strategies—both corporate and the business unit—are tightly aligned and that successful implementation can follow. \r \r This topic will help you understand what strategy is, the elements of a strategic plan, and the strategic planning process. \r \r You will also learn to develop action plans for strategic initiatives that support your company's strateg...
2   158021  Marketing   Presenter: Chad Sesser
3   68640   DLR_AO_UPD-California Screamin' 100705  Attractions Operations Cast Member On-the-Job Training
```

In [15]:

But I am getting this Python Runtime Recursion error. I never got this earlier when I used such a code.

```
/Users/i854319/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _infer_type(obj)
    967     else:
    968         try:
--> 969             return _infer_schema(obj)
    970         except TypeError:
    971             raise TypeError("not supported type: %s" % type(obj))

... last 2 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

/Users/i854319/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in _infer_schema(row)
    992         raise TypeError("Can not infer schema for type: %s" % type(row))
    993 
--> 994     fields = [StructField(k, _infer_type(v), True) for k, v in items]
    995     return StructType(fields)
    996 

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: what's in `content_catalogue`, please make your code fully reproducible.

Comment: Added the details

Comment: you should consider cleaning up your columns containing text.

Comment: That I am thinking of doing it in Spark. So before that need to convert it to Spark data frame .

Comment: And while converting I see the problem